# How to send a POST/GET request from a middleware file in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware

I am trying to send a GET request directly in the middleware file but unfortunately I am getting a weird error message. This is my middleware file:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.next();

  await fetch(new URL("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=postman").href, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  return response;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I try that, the error message is:

> [TypeError: Cannot delete property 'Symbol(set-cookie)' of
> #]

Do you have any idea why I'm getting this error message?

Comment: If you're using `await`, why are you mixing it up with `.then(` and `.catch`? https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-fetch-async-await/

Comment: Actually it doesn't really affect the code above but you're right I should've used just await. thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it. Here is an example how we send a POST request.

```
fetch(new URL("/endpoint", "http://yourdomain.com"), {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    type: "PAGE_REQUESTED",
  })
});
```

Sending GET request is simple as well - just change method: "POST" to method: "GET", and remove the body.

We do not await the request because we don't want it to delay our application. So if this a GET request just use .then in order to get the data